# connected unsecured wifi connection in my hostel but when connected it says "unidentified network no internet access"

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

in my hostel there is a wifi connection with no password when i tried to connect it, it says "connected" but it has a notification which says "unidentified network no internet access" i am using win 7 64 bit ultimate. but this wifi is connecting to my mobile successfully.

i don't  have much access to wifi modem it is just infront of my room with full signal strength which owner boxed it in a seperate box for security. may be i can just restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set IP and DHCP acquisition to automatic in your network settings.

Comment: then how can it be only granted to my mobile? its working in my mobile . and i am sure hostel staff are not technically sound. they just called a guy(who knows it,any ISP) he just intalled it and gone. and more important its working in my mobile. what might be  the problem in my PC can you troubleshoot it?

Comment: Alright, I didn't get that you already got access with your mobile. Make sure that your network settings are set to automatic IP and DHCP.